# How to add multiple line breaks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want when a person adds any list in the first textarea and click button then in next textarea list should have multiple line breaks. My following code only adds one line break. I want it should add 2, 3.. line breaks.

**Please refer this image:**

[image]

**Code:**

```js
function myFunction() {

document.getElementById('TextInput2').value = document.getElementById('TextInput1').value.replace(/[\r\n]{2,}/g, "\n");

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 

 <textarea autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput1" name="message" rows="10" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
 <br><br>
 
 <center><button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button></center>
 
 <br>
 <textarea autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput2" name="message" rows="10" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify 2 (or any other number of) line feeds in the replacement string and apply the substitution on occurrences of 1 and more line feeds. The examples assume that a 'line feed' is either `\n` or the sequence `\r\n`:

**Replace with 2 line breaks**

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('TextInput2').value =
         document.getElementById('TextInput1').value.replace(/(\r?\n)+/g, "\n\n");
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 

 <textarea autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput1" name="message" rows="10" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
 <br><br>
 
 <center><button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button></center>
 
 <br>
 <textarea autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput2" name="message" rows="10" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**Add 2 line breaks**

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('TextInput2').value =
         document.getElementById('TextInput1').value.replace(/((\r?\n)+)/g, "$1\n\n");
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 

 <textarea autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput1" name="message" rows="10" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
 <br><br>
 
 <center><button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button></center>
 
 <br>
 <textarea autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput2" name="message" rows="10" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not adding 2 line breaks

Comment: Do you want to _add_ 2 line breaks to the existing number of line breaks or do you want to _end up_ with 2 line breaks altogether ?

Comment: I want it should have 2 line breaks as shown in image. Like my list already have one line break I want one more to it.

Comment: See the second alternative. Frankly, your image does not convey what your intent is (at least to me) and demonstrating what a html section should be rendered like using an image in an environment where you can use html snippets seems suboptimal ...

Comment: Ok, I just want add line breaks based on my requirements like Apple Banana should have 2 line breaks then 3 line breaks so on... Do you know how I can do that?